# Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I am trying to run following code

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.uprs.config.AppConfig;
import org.uprs.model.POC;
import org.uprs.repository.POCRepository;

public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
    POC person = new POC();
    person.setID(2l);
    person.setName("Rohit");
    person.setOwner("Mishra");
    person.setEngagement("Pune");
    context.getBean(POCRepository.class).save(person);
}
}
```

My Config classes are :

AppConfig.class

```
package org.uprs.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan( basePackages = "org.uprs.services")
@Import({RepositoryConfig.class})
public class AppConfig{
}
```

RepositoryConfig.class

```
package org.uprs.config;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"org.uprs.repository"})
public class RepositoryConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("admin");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean 
    public Map<String, Object> jpaPropertyMap(){ 
        Map<String, Object> jpaProperties = new HashMap<>(); 
        jpaProperties.put("javax.persistence.validation.mode", "none"); 
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.event.merge.entity_copy_observer", "allow"); 
        return jpaProperties; 
    } 

    /** 
     * Configuration object required by Hibernate 
     * @return EntityManagerFactoryBean 
     */ 
    @Bean 
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() { 
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean(); 
        emf.setDataSource(dataSource()); 
        emf.setPackagesToScan("org.uprs.model"); 
        emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter()); 
        emf.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaPropertyMap()); 
        return emf; 
    } 

    /** 
     * Configuration object required by Hibernate 
     * @return JpaVendorAdapter 
     */ 
    @Bean 
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() { 
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter(); 
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true); 
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"); 
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter; 
    } 

    /** 
     * Configuration object required by Hibernate 
     * @return JpaTransationManager 
     */ 
    @Bean 
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() { 
        JpaTransactionManager txnMgr = new JpaTransactionManager(); 
        txnMgr.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject()); 
        return txnMgr; 
    } 
}
```

My model class is :
POC.class

```
package org.uprs.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="contacts")
public class POC {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    Long ID;

    @Column(name="Name")
    String Name;


    @Column(name="Owner")
    String Owner;

    @Column(name="Engagement")
    String engagement;

    public Long getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(Long ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String Name) {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public String getOwner() {
        return Owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(String Owner) {
        this.Owner = Owner;
    }

    public String getEngagement() {
        return engagement;
    }

    public void setEngagement(String engagement) {
        this.engagement = engagement;
    }
}
```

My Repository Class IS : POCRepository Class

```
package org.uprs.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.uprs.model.POC;

public interface POCRepository extends CrudRepository<POC, Long> {

}
```

My Service Class is  :

```
package org.uprs.services;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.uprs.model.POC;
import org.uprs.repository.POCRepository;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/poc")
public class POCService {

    @Autowired
    POCRepository pocRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<POC> getPOCDetails(){
        return (List<POC>) pocRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

I am running the main class and getting following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' defined in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84)
    at test.main(test.java:9)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.<init>(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.defaultServletHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:456)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$23112fed.CGLIB$defaultServletHandlerMapping$39(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$23112fed$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d0aceb5c.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$23112fed.defaultServletHandlerMapping(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 14 more
```

my web.xml details are

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>UPRS</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>org.uprs.config.AppConfig</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Kindly Help me

Comment: You are trying to configure web related features in a non web environment...

Comment: What should be done in main class so that i can mock test the code of inserting data

Answer (score 0):

Please use @WebAppConfiguration instead of @EnableWebMvc as you are in test environment.

Comment: My earlier problem got solved by removing @EnableWebMVC.now the issue is when i am hitting below url http://localhost:8080/UPRS/services/poc/all .It is telling no resources.

Comment: isn't `@EnableWebMvc` a predicated annotation now? Just for clearification.

Comment: Please check if you have mvc:annotation-driven tag and component scan pointing to the rest controller package.

Comment: The issue got solved.I only made some mistake in web.xml.

Answer (score 0):

While using main class,kindly remove @EnableWebMVC and run.It will work fine.